# Passing data from html to python

Tags: python, html, django

It is necessary to obtain information from the selected cell from the html file and then work with it in views.py. Is it possible and how to do it? Thank you in advance!

```
<tbody>
        {% for element in qz %}
            <tr>
                <td class="counterCell"></td>
                <td style="display: none">{{ element.0 }}</td> <!-- information is needed for this cell when it is selected -->
                <td>{{ element.1 }}</td>
                <td>{{ element.2 }}</td>
                <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
```

**views.py:**

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor1 = connection.cursor()
    cursor2 = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(
        "SELECT sites.site_title, sites.url FROM sites, my_sites, auth_user WHERE auth_user.id = my_sites.id_user AND sites.id = my_sites.id_site AND auth_user.id =" + str(
            request.user.id))
    cursor1.execute(
        "SELECT sites.site_title, sites.url FROM sites, my_sites, auth_user WHERE auth_user.id = my_sites.id_user AND sites.id = my_sites.id_site AND auth_user.id =" + str(
            request.user.id))
    cursor2.execute(
        "SELECT sites.id, sites.site_title, sites.url FROM sites, my_sites, auth_user WHERE auth_user.id = my_sites.id_user AND sites.id = my_sites.id_site AND auth_user.id =" + str(
            request.user.id))

    q = [str(row[0]) for row in cursor.fetchall()]

    z = [str(row[1]) for row in cursor1.fetchall()]

    x = [str(row[0]) for row in cursor2.fetchall()]

    qz = [(x[i], q[i], z[i]) for i in range(len(q))]

    return render(request, 'main/my_newsagent.html', {'qz': qz})
```

Comment: post a views.py file here

Comment: Do yourself (and whoever will have to maintain this code) a favor and learn to properly use Django models (and forms etc).  [The offcial tutorial is here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/), please come back when you've done it all.

Comment: PS: given your question, you certainly want to learn about html forms and the HTTP protocol too.

Answer (score 0):

That what you showing is a template. Template receive a data from a view function.
So that function located in a views.py returning that template, with interpolated data (rendered final html). So in may be in context or in other variable.

Comment: Sorry, but I don’t know what to do, where to start .. I'm a newbie